# Error inflating class NavigationView

Tags: java, android, navigationview

I'm getting this error when running my app. Any ideas ?   I am using Android Studio and SDK 22.

```
Process: com.example.sv_laptop03.app, PID: 21717
java.lang.RuntimeException: 
Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.sv_laptop03.app/com.example.sv_laptop03.app.LoggedIn}: android.view.InflateException:Binary XML file line #123: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
```

here is the xml its referring to :

```
        <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/navigation_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/headerview"
        app:menu="@menu/drawer"
        app:itemTextColor="#ffffff"/>
     </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Headerview.xml :Headerview.xml :Headerview.xml :Headerview.xml :Headerview.xml :Headerview.xml :

```
         <LinearLayout        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/headerbg"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:orientation="vertical"><!--
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/profileName"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"/>
-->
    <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
        android:id="@+id/profileImage"
        android:layout_width="90dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:src="@drawable/snapchainappicon"
        app:border_width="2dp"
        app:border_color="#2E7D32"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_height="90dp"/><!--

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/viewProfile"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:text="View Profile"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"/>-->
     </LinearLayout>
```

Here is the XML FOR menu/drawer. xml file

```
 <group android:checkableBehavior="single">
      <item
        android:id="@+id/itemAbout"
        android:title="How it works"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_help_black_24dp"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/itemNetworks"
        android:title="Friends"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_contacts_black_24dp"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/itemShare"
        android:title="Share"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_share_black_24dp"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/itemSettings"
        android:title="Settings"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_settings_black_24dp" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/itemFeedback"
        android:title="Feedback"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_feedback_black_24dp"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/itemLogOut"
        android:title="Log out"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_power_settings_new_black_24dp"/>
     </group>
     </menu>
```

Comment: 1. Make sure you add compile support design. 2. Show your xml, maybe you add some wrong config so the layout failed to create.

Comment: Updated the question with xml

Comment: can you also show the xml of `@layout/headerview` and `@menu/drawer`?

Comment: added these xmls now to the question

Comment: Do you add `compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:1.3.0'` to grade? Also the `drawer` xml is missing the open `<menu>` tag, this is only the copy mistake? I copy your xml and it works

Comment: Yes circleimageview is compiled in grade. and yeah i just miss copy/paste. it has menu in the full xml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Check you add your activity on manifest file or not
2. it might happen if you are trying on lower end devices.

Comment: You were right it was just not showing on a low end emulator. Works fine on my phone. Thanks